# Cannot log in to SQL 2012 - no known login

Tags: security, authentication, sql-server-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a MSSQL user's password?](https://serverfault.com/questions/54109/how-to-recover-a-mssql-users-password)

We recently installed SQL 2012 on one of our servers, but have been unable to log in.  Another tech did the installation so I don't have the details, but I *suspect* that he did not configure a login account, either SQL or Windows Authentication.  How can I get in to my own SQL server without knowing a valid login?

Edit: Before anyone asks, it definitely appears to be an authentication issue.  The exact message from SQL Server Management Studio is "Login failed for user ''. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456".  Also, the SQL service account has been set to use the user account that I am trying to log in as, which I would have thought would be enough to let me in